# Cucumber dependency injection @Scope("cucumber-glue") is not registered

Tags: java, spring, cucumber-jvm

**Problem:** I am trying to have a number of classes scoped once for every scenario of my cucumber parallel tests, as of right now I am getting data contamination because the data in which these 3 objects manage is leaking into subsequent scenarios.

Firstly, I am configuring spring using the following dependencies:

**Spring version: 4.3.16.RELEASE,**
**Cucumber version: 2.4.0**

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sql2o/sql2o -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sql2o</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql2o</artifactId>
            <version>${sql20.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

my world is relatively simple, all scenario data resides in these services and the world looks like so:

```
@Slf4j
public class CucumberWorld {

    @Autowired
    private DataBaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Autowired
    private Driver driver;

    @Autowired @Getter
    private FolderDataService folderDataService;

    @Autowired @Getter
    private UserDataService userDataService;

    @Autowired @Getter
    private AccountDataService accountDataService;
```

Other things to note, I have a `Driver` object which is a bean, and a singleton.  I have various `PageObjects` which are again, all singleton.  My Page objects on 2-3 occassions contain an @Autowired instance variable for these services, for example:

```
@Slf4j
public class LoginPage extends AbstractBasePageObject {

    @Getter
    @Autowired
    private CookieModalComponent cookieModal;
    @Getter
    @Autowired
    private RegistrationModalComponent registrationModal;
    @Getter
    @Autowired
    private PrivacyNoticeModalComponent privacyModal;
    @Autowired
    AccountDataService accountDataService;
```

The Driver + PageObjects should be singletons and last throughout the entire test lifecycle, with these services being reset for each individual scenario.

When I build my bean like so:

```
@Bean
@Scope("cucumber-world")
public AccountDataService accountDataService() {
return new AccountDataService();
}
```

I receive the following:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'world': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'cucumber-world'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1268)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'cucumber-world'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    ... 40 more
```

here is my spring configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class ProductSpringConfiguration extends SpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public FolderDataService folderDataService() {
        return new FolderDataService();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccountDataService accountDataService() {
        return new AccountDataService();
    }

@Bean
public LoginPage loginPage() {
    return new LoginPage(driver());
}
```

Both the Driver bean and the parent spring config class are inherited from a common dependency, the Driver bean is a simple singleton like so:

```
@Bean
public Driver driver() {
 return new Driver();
}
```

Comment: In order to use your own custom scope `cucumber-world`, you have to register additional scope using https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/CustomScopeConfigurer.html

Comment: thanks @SagarRohankar, however this scope is part of the `cucumber-spring` dependency I thought, do I need to configure it before?

Comment: my bad, didnt know that scope is already defined in one of the `cucmber` jar. Can you add `@ComponentScan("cucumber.pacakage.where.that.scope.class.reside")` to you main application config class and try.

Comment: The title mentions `cucumber-glue` while your error and code both mention `cucumber-world`. You may have to correct this.

Comment: Add @DirtiesContext to your step definitions.

Comment: Afaik, it should be `@Scope("cucumber-glue")` and cucumber-spring will make sure to refresh for each scenario run.